# Is it possible to set CSS styles for iframe in loaded file?

Tags: css, html, iframe

I use Iframe in page. This Iframe loads HTML file. I want to stylize this Iframe from is loaded HTML. Is it possible?

```
<iframe style="width:600px;height:525px;border:0;position:absolute;right:0;bottom:30px;" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="widget.html"></iframe>
```

Can I move styles to `widget.html`?

Comment: It's only possible if the page is loaded from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those styles are working, you can simplify it a bit by moving the current in-line styles to a `stylesheet` or move them to `<style>` tags on the html page itself and only call one class like `class="iframestyle"`

As far as what styles you can manipulate iFrames with, here is an article you might want to read: [How to style iFrames - Styling iFrames with CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/iframes-and-css.htm)

Comment: make sure you're adding the stylesheet in the head of the HTML page.  I like to put my stylesheets inside a folder named CSS. So my page would look like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">